# New Error Using Blastula Package in Combination with Gmail: Error in curl_fetch_memory(smtp_server, handle = h) : Login denied

Tags: r, shiny, blastula

I recently encountered this error when sending emails from a Shiny app using the Blastula package while accessing Gmail account:

```
Error in curl_fetch_memory(smtp_server, handle = h) : Login denied
```

I had been using this app for several years without issue until just now. I looked around for solutions and tried quite a few recommendations from older posts but was not able to resolve the issue. I have since found a solution to the error so I thought I would post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google recently changed their security settings, and now it is necessary (at least as far as I can tell) to create an **app password after enabling 2-factor authentication** to use this package.

[Information on setting up and using Google app passwords can be found here.](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en)

Once you've created the password, you'll just need to re-create your credentials file using the new app password. This might not affect many people but I spent quite a lot of time trying to fix this simple problem and thought it may help some who are also stuck.